# How to change mount point?

Tags: 12.04, disk, disk-usage

During Ubuntu 12.04 installation I selected mount point for a 145GB drive to `/usr/local`. How can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just search in dash for `disks` and then edit the mount points of the secondary drives using the Edit Mount Points option- [image: here is the screen-short]

information gathered from [here.](https://askubuntu.com/q/311831/192102) as its similar.

Answer (score 0):

unmount it using `umount` command, create a new directory where you wanna create a new mount point and mount it there using `mount` command